# How to change the result set in SQL developer from Text to grid( tabular format)?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL developer Version 4.0.0.13 where I tried to get the query results in grid i:e tabular format.Currently its showing in text format. I googled to get the answer but couldn't get some relevant answer on it.

Also,after running the query my result window is going to the last of the result. Do we have an option to display the result start from column name?

Comment: May I know which key you are using for executing the query?

Comment: Are you doing run statement (ctrl-enter, or the green 'play' button) or sun script (F5 or the play-button-plus-document button next to it)?

Comment: I normally use F5 key to execute the query. On CTRL-ENTER its showing in tabular format. Interesting stuff in SQL developer. Thanks for the information.